# score aggregation service

Tags: leaderboards

Before i write my own asp.net app, i wanted to see if there is an existing service already.
What i am looking for is send # of zombies the player killed at the end of game to the service. The service than shows sum of all zombies killed that day in the world by other players. 
It will also show top 3 players by their summed score today, not their best score in one game.
Is there such service available or do i have to roll out my own?
thanks

Moderator marked this as duplicate of [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46155/ready-to-use-leaderboard-service-is-any) but the service mentioned in the topic is no longer in service.

Comment: What's your platform? There may be a standard one available (e.g. Game Center for iOS)

Comment: it is targetting android, ios, facebook. The game is written in html5 so any webservice would do

Comment: Whether or not the answers on the duplicate are still functional or not, this question is still a duplicate (and still off topic in any event, as we don't do technology recommendations here).

Comment: Where would you go to find technology recommendations such as this one?